# Magento2: Block not created from controller

Tags: magento2, custom-block

How to create block from controller by ajax method?

```
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Module\Ajaxcart\Block\BuildProductInfo')
        ->setTemplate('Module_Ajaxcart::buildproductinfo.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
```

Showing Cache Exception Error

Comment: Please share your full  code of `execute()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
){
      $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
} 
public function execute() 
{

     $layout = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

     $block = $layout->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Module\Ajaxcart\Block\BuildProductInfo')
                    ->setTemplate('Module_Ajaxcart::buildproductinfo.phtml')
                    ->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: We need to clean the cache?

Comment: you need to setup:upgrade also

Comment: You can also define cache behavior in controller https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you soon.

Comment: ok nop happy coding

Comment: public function writeClose()
    {
        session_write_close();
    }

Comment: got the error when i debug the code.

Comment: error ??????????

Comment: Open the session file and called the writeClose() and then process stoped.

Comment: Which Line after called writeclose() function ??

Comment: When i come on $block line then called writeclose() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94206/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rk-rathod).

Answer (score 1):

You don't send a response from your ajax controller.

**result factory type should be json**

> ```
> $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
> ```

**Code Sample:**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Magento\Contact\Controller\Index;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
>
> class AjaxCall extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
> {
>     public function __construct(
>        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
>     ) {
>         parent::__construct($context);
>     }
>     public function execute() {
>         $this->_view->loadLayout();
>         $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
>         $customBlock = $layout->createBlock(
>             \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm::class,
>             'ajax.contact-us',
>             ['data' => ['id' => 'test']]
>         )->setTemplate('Magento_Contact::form.phtml');
>
>         $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
>         return $resultJson->setData(
>                 [
>                     'html' => $customBlock->toHtml(),
>                     'message' => __('my message')
>                 ]
>             );
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Source class "\Module\Ajaxcart\Controller\Cart\Result" for "Module\Ajaxcart\Controller\Cart\ResultFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: Please share your code and some issue at depency injection

Comment: Can you share chat box

Comment: Post your full code controller at chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94208/magento2-block-not-created-from-controller